# bouncing game displays multiple balls

Tags: c, command-line, for-loop

I am making a pong-like game that is displayed in command prompt, and I have encountered a problem. I have a function that is used to display the game field and the position of the ball:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "ball.h"
#include "field.h"

void display (field f, ball b)
{
    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
    for (int h = 0; h < 10; ++h)//
    {
        cout << "\n\t|";
        for (int w = 0; w < 20; ++w)
        {
            cout << "  ";
            if (b.x = w && b.y == h) cout << "o";
            else cout << ".";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
}
```

When I run the program, the field is shown correctly, but instead of a single ball, an entire row(the correct row) is filled up with 'o's.

So if the ball's coordinates were (5, 5), the entire 5th row would be 'o's.

I've tried commenting out all of the other functions in my main(), and this is still a problem. Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated, I am stumped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning instead of comparing here:

```
if (b.x = w && b.y == h) cout << "o";
//      ^
```

so whenever `w` is non-zero, `b.x=w` is evaluated as **true**. It should be

```
if (b.x == w && b.y == h) cout << "o";
//      ^^
```

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe I missed that for so long. Thank you for the very fast reply, I feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a "=" in `if (b.x = w && b.y == h) cout << "o"`;

Thus b.x = w will always evaluate to True

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it would be the typo in your line:

```
if (b.x = w && b.y == h) cout << "o";
```

You have an error by saying "b.x = w" instead of "b.x == w". Fix that up and everything should be running fine.